# iOS option is disabled in Version or platform (iTunes Connect)

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app to the App Store using xcode. I can see my build in my existing app on iTunes connect. However when I want to add the build using the "+ Version or platform" option it shows me a disabled iOS button:

My build version is 2.0.

[image]

I received an email from Apple stating that the app completed processing. Any reason why I can't select it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case I wanted to update the app to a newer version which wasn't listed in the "+Version or Platform" menu. The possible reason is that a previous build failed, with the status of "Prepare for Submission".

1. Select the build which is listed as "Prepare for submission" under "iOS App".
2. Scroll down till you see the build for that submission.
3. Delete the old build and select a new correct build.
4. Now scroll down more and change the version of your submission in the textfield to the build number of your correct build.

After doing that I was able to submit it to the App Store.

Comment: You can edit the version number using the text box even before removing the previous build. This is helpful if you do not have a new build yet.

Comment: One would expect a better user interface from Apple. Graying out UI elements with no explanation is a major no-no.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. I had to reject an app that was in "Waiting for Review" status since we had to update a bug that we found after we submitted the previous build. Once we did that, we were unable to add a new version and the ios option was disabled. To fix this:

1. I went to the same version that showed "Rejected by Developer",
2. Scrolled down to the build version,
3. Clicked the minus (-) icon next to the previous build to remove that,
4. Added the new build and
5. Saved and Submitted for review.

The version increment automatically updated after step 5 above based on the selected build.

Comment: Thanks @Neel that worked for me, I can't believe it's so clunky to request a review and hold the app for manual release (I use the 'Manually release this version' option to get it reviewed), but on this occasion we decided to do a couple of tweaks and so we will get it reviewed again and will release it when we are happy it's the right time.

Answer (score 0):

GrangerFX has the answer.

In the App Store click on your app, then the version number under iOS App on left.
This will open the Prepare for Submission screen on right (unless you already did that).

Scroll down to "Build" section, and click the "do not enter" sign, which is some secret code that means delete (rather than a typical trash can). [Nice UI Apple! Keep trying, maybe you will get it right one day.]

Then you will be asked to pick a build. Choose your latest uploaded build.