# iOS disabled inside version or platform (itunes connect)

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to upload iOS apps to update my apps version. But the icon iOS in version or platform cannot be clicked

I already looked the solutions on [iOS option is disabled in Version or platform (iTunes Connect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616252/ios-option-is-disabled-in-version-or-platform-itunes-connect)

Select the build which is listed as "Prepare for submission" under "iOS App".
Scroll down till you see the build for that submission.
Delete the old build and select a new correct build.
Now scroll down more and change the version of your submission in the textfield to the build number of your correct build.

BUT I never found delete button. So I cannot delete the old build.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the page as u scroll down you will find - sign button ,click on that button and your rejected build will be deleted and upload the new build

Comment: Did you click on prepare for submission build ? because when I scroll down to end of the page I do not find any

Comment: You have to click on rejected build and then scroll down to the end of the page , there you will find a red color minus button. Click on that button and your build will be deleted successfully.