# App showing in activity tab in App Store Connect but can't publish

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to update my app to the apple store. I build it and got the email saying:

```
The following build has completed processing:
Platform: iOS
App Name: MyApp
Build Number: 103
Version Number: 1.3
You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.
```

When I check my activity tab in app store connect, the app is there (v1.3). The app is also in the testflight tab.
But on the tab App Store, in the section IOS APP is not showing.

How can I publish my app?

[image]

Comment: click on + version or Plateform

Comment: @guru I updated the question with an image that shows the + version or platform click

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37620269/2928241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more than 2 versions (one "live", one "edit") for one iOS app.

Simply remove the build from the "Developer Rejected" version and add the new one. Then you can submit the app for review.